# Are $-A, \ A^T, \ A+B$ are strictly diagonally dominant as per rows?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

If $A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are strictly diagonally dominant as per rows, then check if $-A, \ A^T, \ A+B$ are strictly diagonally dominant as per rows.

We have that:

A square matrix $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant if for all rows the absolute value of the diagonal element in a row is strictly greater than the sum of absolute value of the rest of the elements in that row.

- $-A$ is also strictly diagonally dominant because we check the elements with their absolute values,which are equal to these of $A$.
- $A^T$ is not necesarily strictly diagonally dominant, because in this case it would mean that for all columns in $A$ the absolute value of the diagonal element in a column is strictly greater than the sum of absolute value of the rest of the elements in that column in $A$, which we don't know.
- We have that $\displaystyle{|a_{ii}|>\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|}$ and  $\displaystyle{|b_{ii}|>\sum_{i\neq j}|b_{ij}|}$, but we have that $|a_{ii}+b_{ii}|<|a_{ii}|+|b_{ii}|$ and so we cannot conculde that $A+B$ is also strictly diagonally dominant.

Is everything correct?

Comment: It might be better to prove $A^t$ By example, I.e. $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\\ 0&3\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: We have that $A^T=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 2 & 3\end{pmatrix}$ which would mean that $A^T$ is also strictly diagonally dominant? @razivo

Answer (score 1):

No, points 1 and 2 are correct, but point 3 is flawed. You have $$|a_{ii}+b_{ii}| \leq |a_{ii}| + |b_{ii}|,$$ rather than $$|a_{ii}+b_{ii}| \leq |a_{ii}| + |b_{ii}|.$$ Regardless, this inequality contains no information about the relationship between the diagonal values of $C=A+B$ and the off diagonal values of $C$.

Instead consider the choice of $B=-A$. If $A$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows, then so is $B$, but $C=0$ is not strictly diagonally dominant by rows. Similarly, if $B=A$, then $C=2A$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows.

These two examples show that we cannot conclude that $C=A+B$ is strictly diagonally dominant by rows if our information is limited to the fact that $A$ and $B$ are both strictly diagonally dominant by rows.

Comment: I understand!! Is my justification for points 1 and 2 complete? Or is something missing? For point to give a counterexample can we consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & 1 \\ 7 & 8 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$ But $A^T=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 7 & 1 \\ 2 & 8 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$ is not strictly diagonally dominant by rows, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, point 2 can be strengthened by adding an example. Your 3-by-3 matrix is not diagonally dominant in the second row. Try $A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$ which is strictly diagonally dominant by rows, but not strictly diagonally dominant by columns.